# Adding color code translation for a string in a Bukkit config.yml

Tags: java, plugins, colors, bukkit

I am trying to add color support to my plugin and when I did, it works, but i get a weird symbol on the left side of it. ([image: http://postimg.org/image/5tuimwlsb/]). Here is my code:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
{
    if(sender instanceof Player)
        {
            Player player = (Player)sender;

            if(player.hasPermission("di.use"))
                { 
                if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("di"))
                {
                if(args.length == 0)
                {
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "+" + ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "---------------" + ChatColor.GREEN+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "[" + ChatColor.YELLOW+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "DonationInfo" + ChatColor.GREEN+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "]" + ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "--------------" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "+");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "/di" + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD+ " Spinel " + ChatColor.BLUE+""+ChatColor.BOLD + " - " + ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "Spinel Donation Info");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "/di" + ChatColor.DARK_BLUE+""+ChatColor.BOLD+ " Sapphire " +  ChatColor.BLUE+""+ChatColor.BOLD + " - " + ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "Sapphire Donation Info");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "/di" + ChatColor.RED+""+ChatColor.BOLD+ " Ruby " +  ChatColor.BLUE+""+ChatColor.BOLD + " - " + ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "Ruby Donation Info");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "/di" + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE+""+ChatColor.BOLD+ " Amethyst " +  ChatColor.BLUE+""+ChatColor.BOLD + " - " + ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "Amethyst Donation Info");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "+" + ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "-----------------------------------------" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "+");
                    return true;
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
            }
        }else{
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Your do not have permissions to use this command!");
        }
            if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Spinel"))
            {String a = getConfig().getString("Spinel");
            String coloredText = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('§', a);
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                player.sendMessage(coloredText);
                return true;
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
            if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Sapphire"))
            {String b = getConfig().getString("Sapphire");
            String coloredText = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('§', b);
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                player.sendMessage(coloredText);
                return true; 
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
            if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Ruby"))
            {String c = getConfig().getString("Ruby");
            String coloredText = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('§', c);
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                player.sendMessage(coloredText);
                return true;
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
            if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Amethyst"))
            {String d = getConfig().getString("Amethyst");
            String coloredText = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('§', d);
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                player.sendMessage(coloredText);
                return true;
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
            if(player.hasPermission("di.admin"))
            {
                if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("reload"))
                {
                                        this.reloadConfig();
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD+"[Donation_Info]" + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + " || " + ChatColor.AQUA+""+ChatColor.BOLD + "Plugin reloaded!");
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: [What research have you already done on the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Have you read the [JavaDocs](http://jd.bukkit.org/beta/doxygen/d7/dc0/enumorg_1_1bukkit_1_1ChatColor.html#a8adf25d607a159c3ab6dcc1ba4403a5c) for `ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes`?

Answer (score 1):

First off, just thought that I would point out that this is `Java`. Bukkit plugins are coded with `Java`. Java is to JavaScript as car is to carrot... Your code is not in JavaScript.

Anyways, the reason your code is not working properly is because you cannot use the `§` symbol for Minecraft, because MineCraft does not allow all special characters, So when you try to translate Color Codes with it, it `DOES` work, but the `§` is not removed, but instead replaced with `Å`.

If you want to translate alternate color codes, you can use `ChatColor.translateAlternetColorCodes(Char, String)`. So, let's say that for example you wanted to make a message green, having the message *Hi*. You could use:

```
String toTranslate = "&4Donation 1";
String translated = ChatColor.translateAlternetColorCodes('&', toTranslate);
```

The string `translated` would then become `ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Donation 1"`.

You could change the `&` in the arguments for the first line of code to any other character, for example you could use `$`. If you used `$`, then `$4Donation 1` would also ake a dark red message that says "Hi". You cannot use the `§` symbol, though, and some other special characters for translating color codes.

Here is a complete list of color codes: [List Here](http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/4/4c/Colors.png)

If you really need to use the `§` symbol for some reason, you **MAY** be able to get away with it by doing this:

```
String toTranslate = "§4Donation 1";
String translated = ChatColor.translateAlternetColorCodes('§', toTranslate)
String final = translated.replaceAll("Å", "") //replace the special characters with nothing, but keep the color
```

The above might work, although I don't recommend it because it's a little bit messy, you have to `UTF-8` (not that it's bad), and it's also a lot harder to create the `§` symbol than it is to create the `&` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a `§` then you don't need to do anything; I do believe that minecraft parses the color codes using special characters on its own.

You would only need to use `translateAlternateColorCodes(...)` when it is not the symbol `§`.

Otherwise, jojodmo explains it pretty well.